# How to make background image as responsiveness in all screens

Tags: css

I just created about us page  and added banner as background image.When i reduce the screen the image is getting dissorted.It is not responsive to all the screens.Here is the css

```
section.titlebar {
background: url(../images/team-bg03.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;    
background-position: 0px 89px !important;
height: 914px;}
```

Tried by adding this

```
 section.titlebar {
background: url(../images/team-bg03.jpg);   
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
}
```

If i am giving background size as contain it is not getting the full width banner but i need to get as full width banner

Answer (score 0):

The `cover` property is what you're looking for. However - this may lead to some cropping of the image at different breakpoints.

```css
section.titlebar {
   background: url(../images/team-bg03.jpg);   
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
   background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: Image should not crop at any sizes need to get full image

Comment: @user2630366 Unless the image's aspect ratio *always* matches that of it's parent, you aren't going to be able to achieve this without either distortion or cropping.